# Using one variable frequency drive for 2 motors (one at a time)

Tags: vfd

Is there any issue using one VFD, to run 2 motors— one at a time using a selector switch?  So 3 phase in the the VDF— the frequency is modified and comes out the VDF— into a switch intended to switch between mains and a genset— with one motor on each of the positions for the switch.  So only one gets power at a time.

Forgive my ignorance, what I have in my head is a potential problem if one was to switch between the motors when under load.  Maybe going from max load to nothing, then back to being under load would be a problem?

The reason I consider this is because of what can happen with relays that don’t have a diode.   If I understand correctly the collapsing magnetic field from the coil causes a big voltage spike.  I know this is not the same thing…AC vs DC and all that, but electric motors have windings and coils do too….. so maybe…..????

Anyway I’m remote, this gear is expensive, hard to get and I just don’t what to brake it!

Answer (score 1):

If by a selector switch you mean a 3-pole contactor, one for each motor, then you can as long as you make sure to have the VFD bring the motor comes to a complete stop before disconnecting one motor and connecting the other.

That way, the contactors see no collapsing magnetic field or arcing and the VFD does not malfunction from suddenly having its commutation inputs abruptly change. If you're sane you're not going to try to switchover motors while the VFD is commutating.

> Forgive my ignorance, what I have in my head is a potential problem if one was to switch between the motors when under load. Maybe going from max load to nothing, then back to being under load would be a problem?

No. Just no. Don't do this. Very bad.